# Which user should checkout code from SVN in a Jenkins build job?

Tags: svn, jenkins

I'm setting up Jenkins with Subversion, using the svn+ssh method.

This raises a "best practice" question, should I use my own svn credentials for the checkout or should there be a special Jenkins-user who does the checkout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want others, who have access to Jenkins, to see your credentials? Of course, there should be a separate user for Jenkins. (and he actually needn't to have write access to repository).